# How do I use the Minecraft Coder Pack on Linux

Tags: minecraft-modding

I downloaded the Minecraft coder pack to mod the game and decompile it, but how do I use it on Linux. Some sources seem to give specific directions, but they are not clear and they involve executing the .bat files. My Ubuntu does not recognize .bat file. How do I decompile a class file from changing a Minecraft version jar file to a zip and unzipping it? How do I decompile one of those class files using Minecraft coder pack? I have been wondering what at least some of the Minecraft source code looks like.

Comment: What specific part of a specific tutorial did you find unclear or unsuited to your needs?

Answer (score 0):

I did not try this but you should be able to execute the sh files.
In windows you have .bat and in linux .sh, try to execute the decompile.sh file.
You can do this in terminal, rightclick into an empty space in the folder where the sh file is, then click on "open in terminal".
Type `./decompile.sh`